# Union and Offset in SQL Query

Tags: offset

I need to incorporate pagination based on results fetched from two tables say (T1 and T2). Hence I need to combine UNION and OFFSET TOGETHER. Say I have Field1 and Field2 in Table T1, Field3 and Field 4 in Table T2. I need to fetch certain n rows offset by certain p rows. How can I do it.

Pls note database is SQL Server

Answer (score 2):

**Sample Schema & Values:**

```
CREATE TABLE T1
 ([field1] varchar(10), [field2] varchar(10));

INSERT INTO T1
  ([field1], [field2])
VALUES
 ('Value11', 'Value12'),
 ('Value21', 'Value22'),
 ('Value31', 'Value32');

CREATE TABLE T2
 ([field3] varchar(10), [field4] varchar(10));

INSERT INTO T2
 ([field3], [field4])
VALUES
 ('Value41', 'Value42'),
 ('Value51', 'Value52'),
 ('Value61', 'Value62');
```

**Sample Query for your Requirement**

```
select * from (select field1 as f1, field2 as f2 from T1
union all
select field3 as f1, field4 as f2 from T2) as TAB1
order by f1 offset 0 rows fetch next 2 rows only;
```

**Try it Yourself**

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f9878/4

Comment: Thank you. This has solved my issue. Thanks a ton again